# Are there a kanji for マル and バツ (O and X, right and wrong)

Tags: kanji

AFAIK words マル and バツ are commonly used as short answers (right and wrong, 正しい・正しくない).
Are there any kanji for these words?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

マル means 'circle', and this is clearly the word 丸{まる}.

But the origin of バツ is less clear.   It may be from 罰点{ばってん}, and in fact I've always assumed the correct kanji would (in theory) be 罰, but dictionary editors appear to be less certain.  日本国語大辞典 says:

> 「ばってん（罰点）からできた語か

And 明鏡国語辞典 says:

> 「罰点（ばってん）」からか。

And 大辞林 says:

> 「罰点」から生じた語か

Note the か at the end in each case.  Based on these dictionary entries, I can't state for certain that it would (in theory) be 罰 in kanji, but that's my best guess.

Comment: If one ever used 『罰』, native speakers would take it to mean "punishment" 100% of the time.  No one would take it to mean the "X" mark we get on a test signifying "incorrect answer".  That I could guarantee.

Comment: Ah, maybe I should have emphasized the "would be" part more to make it clear that I was speaking hypothetically.  Thank you for the comment!